# Setting area for BlobAnalysis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, blob, traffic, matlab-cvst

I am using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45951--computer-vision-made-easy--demo-files/content/countingCars.m) example from a Computer Vision Made Easy" Matlab Webinar I watched, since I intend to use Computer Vision for my research in order to count cars and/or other types of vehicles.

Although I have changed some of the filter parameters and the detection works quite well, the problem is that the script displays ALL moving objects in the video. I would like to count vehicles from a specific road but my video screenshot includes many roads (screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0y8f48nc1f8cmjj/screenshot2.png?dl=0)).

1) Is there a way to set the area of the video that I would like to detect cars? For example, only the "green arrow" road, and leave out the rest? I tried to crop the video but it is not a good solution since a part of another road always appears(screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nu5ywzyle5hxdby/screenshot2.png?dl=0)).

2) Moreover, in which part of the code can I add a counter in order to have an output on how many vehicles passed through the specific segment of the road? Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

If you know ahead of time where the road is, you can create a binary mask image, where the road is marked with 1's, and everything else has the value of 0. Then you can simply check whether or not a moving object is inside your region of interest.

Once you get comfortable with this example, check out [a more advanced version](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html), which not only detects moving objects, but also tracks them using the Kalman filter.

Comment: Dima, 

nice idea with the mask. I will try to implement this in the next days.

I have also checked the "advanced" version but there are some problems with assigning a unique track to a vehicle (maybe due to not constant speed of the vehicles in the video).

Also, problems appear due to different directions(but it will solved I guess with the mask idea), as if it assumes that all vehicles moving southbound are then getting in the video northbound, giving them the same track_id.

Comment: A lot depends on your frame rate, and on how fast objects move. Try tweaking parameters. Increasing the `costOfNonAssignment` may help. Also look at the parameters of the Kalman filter.  Increasing `InitialEstimateError` can help to maintain the id. Decreasing it can help to not let the id jump to the wrong car. You have to experiment with it.